# Jhipster v6.10.5 javax.servlet errors in Intellij 2020.3 for maven project

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, jhipster

I was getting the compilation errors in Intellij after importing the maven project. Intellij was complaining about **javax.servlet** package not found. The project is building and running from the command line. I have tried reimporting the project after deleting the .idea folder and other idea files.

Answer (score 1):

After struggling for two half days on this, I stumbled upon this [link](https://cirovladimir.wordpress.com/2017/11/08/jhipster-runs-fine-from-maven-but-not-from-intellij/). It needed a simple toggle of maven profile. Uncheck the **IDE** profile option in the maven tool window.

The Jhipster docs have suggestion on enabling the **IDE** profile. This was causing all the errors.